# List all Locale Identifiers and corresponding region text Swiftui

Tags: swift, swiftui, locale, region

I would like to generate a list of all Locale identifiers for the user to select as a default. Similar to selecting the region in the standard settings.

Thus I would like to generate a list that would contain e.g. "Australia", "Austria", "Azerbaijan", ... ,"Yemen", "Zambia", "Zimbabwe". If the user selects "Australia" I would like to return `en_AU`.

So need to identify the property under `Locale` that can be used and how to iterate through it.

Currently, just trying to see if I can return the text e.g. "Australia":

```
Text(Locale.localizedString(Locale.init(identifier: Locale.availableIdentifiers[0].description)))
```

However returning error:

```
Closure containing control flow statement cannot be used with function builder 'ViewBuilder'
```

Thank you

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: I have tried Locale.availableIdentifiers[0].description as well as a few others isoRegionCodes, isoLanguageCodes. Busy looking here as well: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nslocale

Comment: You should add something to your question that shows you tried something my firend.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Seems like you are looking for the name of each identifier. You can get those from the `NSLocale` like:

```
Locale.availableIdentifiers.map {
    (id: $0, name: (NSLocale.current as NSLocale).displayName(forKey: .languageCode, value: $0) ?? "-")
}
```

So you can rise them as you like. For example, showing them in a list:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    let localeSheet: [(id: String, name: String)] = {
        Locale.availableIdentifiers.map {
            (id: $0, name: (NSLocale.current as NSLocale).displayName(forKey: .languageCode, value: $0) ?? "-")
        }.sorted { $0.name < $1.name }
    }()

    var body: some View {
        List(localeSheet, id: \.id) {
            Text($0.name)
            Spacer()
            Text($0.id)
        }
    }
}
```